# e-mail RDNS lookup

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix, reverse-dns

I'm getting lots of junk "return to delivery" mail on my server, so I would like to add this "RDNS" lookup thing in Ubuntu.

But I can't figure out how. Most documentation is about regular DNS servers.

Comment: You do not specify what software your email server is? Exim? Sendmail? Postfix?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming from the tagging of the question that your mail server software is Postfix, you can tune this via the smtpd_client_restrictions variable as described in [postconf(5)](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html)